# How did windows/c# remember the current systems year/date

Tags: windows-7, c#, visual-studio-2012

Recently i was working with unit testing for my project.

I've given a task to test the method. The method should return the recent quarter date as per the current system date.

So, I've called the current system date using the following c# code:

```
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

When i run the query it worked as expected.

So, its time for my tactics to raise a bug for that method. Hence I've changed the system date to 10/01/14 (dd/mm/yy).

Also I've customized current system date format to only keep last two digits of the year.
Ex: if year is `2014` the it shows only `14`.

You can observe the short date and the long date in the following image.

[image: Customized date]

When i run/debug the test in Visual Studio 2012, it still displays as 2014 as the current system date though I've modified it to 14.

**Question:** The real question is how did the system/program took the current year as 2014 even the system date is changed to 14. It may be silly but my doubt is `Why it is not 1914 or 1814 and why it is 2014 ?`.

Where did it store the current date or year information ? Does windows manage this stuff or did the C# taken care of the date ?

Comment: This seems more like a Stackoverflow question to be honest.  In the end the result of DateTime is based on the default culture and calendar of the system.  If you want to modify the result change the code to a specific format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The real question is how did the system/program took the current year as 2014 even the system date is changed to 14. It may be silly but my doubt is Why it is not 1904 or 1804 and why it is 2014 ?.

C# only retrieved the date from the system, it was Windows that determined what data to send.

In the case of two-digit dates, Windows allows you to define what they mean in the *Regional and Language* applet in the *Control Panel*. This way you can specify the range you want it to represent depending on your usage.

[image: Screenshot of date-format dialog]

Answer (score 2):

The display of a date is not how it is stored, just how it is displayed.

January, 1st, 2014 may have a multitude of different formats, e.g.
2014-01-01
01-01-2014
01-01-14
1/1/14
Jan/1/14
001-2014
But all are held internally exactly the same way.

Note the advanced settings on your screenshot - this will indicate to many windows programs how to interpret a year entered as 2 digits, so it knows if it should regard a date entered as XX as 19XX or 20XX - this will cover manually entered dates, not the system date

Answer (score 1):

Your C# application didn't store that date, Windows handled it for you.

As Sean mentioned, by changing from **YYYY** to **YY** you only changed how the date is **displayed**, not how it is **stored**. Windows doesn't store its system time information into a specific date format. Instead, it records the number of 100-milisecond intervals since 00:00 January 1st, 1601. That way it keeps the tracking of time independent of how it's displayed and allows you to display the date and time in a number of different formats.

As a curiosity, that specific date was chosen because the Gregorian calendar operates on a 400-year cycle (when it starts to repeat itself) and 1601 was the first year of the cycle that was active when Windows NT was being developed.

On a side note, Unix systems store that information as **Unix Time** or **POSIX Time**, counting the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 January 1st 1970.